# How to put a variable in bot.sendMesage (python)

Tags: python, variables, bots, telegram, telepot

I'm creating a telegram bot with python and I can't find the way to make the output of a variable with bot.sendMessage. Can anyone help me please?

```
var = '123'
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "The number is:"var)
```

Comment: Welcome, we aren't mind readers, you would have to show us your code and what you've tired and what went wrong. As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: Since this is python: this is how you concatenate a string: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a python syntax error. You are not concatenating. You can do this for example (but you can use also other ways to concatenate):

```
var = '123'
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "The number is:{}".format(var))
```